# C# store file content to a List<String>

Tags: c#, wpf

What I am trying to achieve:

**Want to read text file and store it in a List of Strings.
Use second List of string to save if found using regex**

I dont know how to tackle this problem but this is what i have done so far.

```
using (StreamReader content = new StreamReader(@file_To_Read))
{

 List <String> newLine = new List <String> ();

 string line;
    while (line = content.ReadLine()) != null) 

 //add line to List
  newLine.Add(line);
}
```

Lets say there is text called 'causes' in some of the lines.What I want is now to iterate through the list or lines whatever is easy and store the line in a new list.

Comment: are you getting something in line after line = content.ReadLine() ?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the list like this

```
List<string> newlist = newLine.Where(x => x.Contains("your string to match")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `File.ReadAllLines`?

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("your_file_path.txt");
```

Or something more to your requirements.

```
List<string> lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("your_file_path.txt").ToList();
```

Comment: What i want is to search through the string list and get the second list using regex.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you want something along these lines?

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); //reads all the lines in the file into the array
string[] causes = lines.Where(line => line.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("causes")).ToArray(); //uses LINQ to filter by predicate
```

Now you have your lines containing the word "causes" in the array named `causes`

Hope, that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

To read all lines into a List you can write the following:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@file_To_Read).ToList();
```

Now if you want a new list with all lines where the word 'causes' appears you can use the following linq-query:

```
List<string> causes = lines.Where(line => line.Contains("causes").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

using (StreamReader content = new StreamReader("FileName"))
            {

```
            List<String> newLine = new List<String>();
            while( ! content.EndOfStream)
            {
                String line = content.ReadLine();                
                if (line.Contains("causes"))
                {
                    //add line to List
                    newLine.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
```